# PDF viewer for windows forms questions

Tags: winforms, pdf, pdfviewer

My project requires viewing of PDF files and I use free PDF viewer from Аpitron for this.
The problem is that I want a notification or some event when the page changes, but can't find it on a control itself. I can't believe that such an obvious thing is missing, did anyone manage to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

as it's written in their documentation this control integrates with existing Navigation services and therefore you may use Document.Navigator.Navigated event and get the current page.